# Apply Local Policy to Terminal Server (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard - Workgroup )

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server

I have created 5 local user in Window server 2008 R2 std in workgroup. This server is also Terminal Server.

Is it possible to apply local user Policy (gpedit.msc) per user wise?

I want to accomplish the following tasks:

1. Restrict some control panel item as per user
2. Software Restriction as per user
3. Hide Administrative tools in control panel and start menu, only to user which has user rights
4. User must not be able to see other user data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my Personal Experience.

Implement the policy whatever you want on one Domain Window PC

After applying the policy, jUst copy from %systemroot%\system32\GroupPolicy to PC which is in Workgroup in the same location.

Limitation:- But it will apply to whole Computer and user

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to apply group policies selectively using a workgroup.

To accomplish this functionality with built in tools you should attach it to a domain and use group policy filters and/or OUs to separate out the users and groups.

as for #4 you can do that with standard permissions so long as none of the users are admins.

You might be able to accomplish the other tasks using registry edits on the user hives after they've been created and logged in, but that is far from ideal.